# Have a column pull criteria from two columns and display specific value

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, calculated-column, sharepoint-library, microsoft-flow

My goal is to have a calculated/or lookup column to display the company number if two columns contain certain information. I do not have access to PowerApps, Microsoft Forms, SharePoint Designer, limited use for Microsoft Access. I do have Microsoft Flow.

What I have is a flow that populates: when a file is uploaded to this document library, the file properties change according to the file name. See screenshot.

[image]

I do have lists with State Abbreviations, legal entity names, and entity numbers as shown below.

- State abbreviations list only has a title column with all 50 state
  abbreviations.
- US Entity States list has the company number listed in
  the title and a "State" lookup column that is linked to the first
  list.
- US Entities has a list of all of the (full) legal names of the
  company as the title, and the company code as a single line of text
  next to it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to use these lists (or possibly edit/create another one if need be) that can help me auto-populate a column in a SharePoint library. For example, if a document is tagged as state "MO" and Nicknamed "Rec", then get the company number for Montana Real Estate, Co. which is 426 as shown below. I added the company number manually, but I would like this to auto-populate.

[image]

I understand I have to somehow show the relationship between "MO" and "Rec" = company 426, but I am not sure how to do so.

**This is the flow I currently use to fill in the State and Company "Nickname" columns:**
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are going in the right direction. You need to have a connection - US Entities with either State Abbreviations or US Entity States. You can create a lookup column in US Entities list for this purpose. You can then use all these lookup values in your FLOW on document is uploaded.

Comment: Also, are 'State', 'Company' & 'US Entity' lookups in the library? If yes, then is 'State' coming from State Abbreviations?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I will try a few combinations of that to see which works best. Also, the State column in the "US Entity States" list is a lookup, coming from the State Abbreviations list. Everything else is a single line of text.

Comment: How would I edit the flow to lookup the values? Is there a "best practice" for this? @harshalgite

Comment: State is a lookup column from State Abbreviations right? because you cannot use a lookup column in another lookup.

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of the flow you have already created in which State and Company is filled from the document name?

Comment: @harshalgite I posted my flow in my original post. I do not remember where I found it. Also, yes, State is a lookup column (coming from the Abbreviations list) located within the US Entity States list.

Comment: In "US Entities" list, Is the Company code linked to the Title in "US Entity States"?

Comment: @harshalgite Yes; the US Entity list column "Company Code" is a lookup from the US Entity States list. The screenshot does not show the usual red link that usually shows up in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your list structures and flow. And without changing your list structure, I have just added 2 actions in your flow and got the ALMOST desired result.

As per your structure, the `US Entity (column which stores the company code in the document library)` is a lookup column to ***US Entities*** list. And, `Company Code` in the ***US Entities*** list. But in SharePoint you cannot display a lookup column of a lookup column in the a list or library. I mean, you cannot show `Company Code` in your document library directly if your `US Entity` column is a lookup to ***US Entities*** list.

You can show the Title "**Montana Real Estate, Co.**" instead of **Company Code** which will be a link to that item in the US Entities list. Please check the screenshots below.

[image]

Detailed actions:
[image]

> State/Title - here State is internal name of the column in the US
>   Entity States list. So replace with your column's internal name.
>   Follow this for the below action as well.

[image]

Expression used is as shown below:

```
first(body('Get_items_US_Entity_States')?['value'])?['State']['Id']
```

[image]

Here, In my case the lookup column in the document library is **US Entity Title** (in your case it is Company Code). So while updating the value of that column in the Power Automate (MS Flow), I have used the below expression.

```
first(body('Get_items_US_Entities')?['value'])?['Id']
```

The library data will look like this
[image]

Hope it helps. Please let me know if this solution is fine or you want the Company code to be displayed and linked to the US Entities list. There is a workaround for that but without really creating a lookup field in the library. Please up-vote and mark as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the file name is always in the format of US Abbreviations_Company nickname name_etc. We shall be able to pick up the two piece of string in Flow.

In the US entity states list, is there a column showing the nickname of the company which will be used in the uploaded file name? If now it will be a bit hard as we have no clue to connect Rec to Montana Real Estate. If we have it, things will not be too tough.

First we try to split the uploaded file name into MO and Rec and save them in two variables, then update the State column with MO. Use Rec to query the US entity states list and find corresponding Full name of company and the company code, and update the last two column in your library.

[How to use substring in flow](https://www.timlinenterprises.com/microsoft-flow-substring/)

[Common Filters for Microsoft Flow: A Reference Chart for Users of all Kinds](https://blog.ion.works/2019/03/17/common-odata-filters-for-microsoft-flow-a-reference-chart-for-users-of-all-kinds/)

Comment: Yes, the naming convention is: SS_nnnnn_qqqqYY_Income Tax (if that makes any sense). 

I guess my question is how to make that column within the US entity states list. Would it be a lookup to another column or can I simply create a "single line of text" column and manually type in the appropriate nickname per company code?

Comment: I am trying to follow the split that you mentioned, but I do not really understand how to do that.